# Reading through an array 2d from center to corners

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d, center

So for this java project I´m working on I need a loop that reads trough an 2d array from center first then 4 adjecent values then the corners of that and keep doing that till it reaches and completes the most outer layer. I need it to work on all odd sizes of square 2d arrays. I made this image to clarify my goal: http://gyazo.com/80ed4502cb16795d37b75a14ee57f565 . I personally was not able to achieve this. Thank you for your time! any piece of pseudo code or java code is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could logically redefine the grid so that the center is 0,0.
Then, sort each grid coordinate according to distance from the center.
This assumes that the grid is an odd width.

For example:

```
class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

Point gridCenter;


Comparator<Point> comparator = new Comparator<Point>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Point arg0, Point arg1) 
    {
        int x = arg0.x - gridCenter.x;
        int y = arg0.y - gridCenter.y;

        int distance0 = x*x + y*y;

        x = arg1.x - gridCenter.x;
        y = arg1.y - gridCenter.y;
        int distance1 = x*x + y*y;


        return distance0 - distance1;
    }
};

void test()
{
    int width = 11;
    int height = 13;

    gridCenter = new Point();
    gridCenter.x = width/2;
    gridCenter.y = height/2;

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int x=0;x<width;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<height;y++)
        {
            Point p = new Point();
            p.x = x;
            p.y = y;

            points.add(p);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(points, comparator);

    for(Point p : points)
    {
        System.out.println(p.x + "," + p.y);
    }

}
```

You could bias center slightly if you want to guarantee that it chooses left,top before right,bottom in the sort.